# How do I clear the cache / history in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, history, cache

In Windows XP there was an option off the task bar properties to clear all recently accessed webpages, recent file lists, ie. cache, temp files and so on; is there an equivalent for Windows 7?

Comment: this is not by default in XP, you probably installed a program that added this feature.

Comment: it is by default, i didnt install any program, u just click properties on the task bar, then under one of the tabs click the clear button

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean...

Comment: its odd, i cant find anything to clear things like like the search bar autocomplete on explorer (which even clearing ie doesnt clear)

Comment: So the Delete Browsing History settings in IE don't work?

Answer (score 0):

2. Right-click on the taskbar or the Windows Orb.
3. Open "Properties".
4. On the "Start Menu" tab, click on "Customize...".
5. In the "Customize Start Menu" windows, check the checkbox "Recent Items".
6. Click OK twice to close the 2 open windows.
7. In the Start Menu, you have now a "Recent Items" entry.
8. If you right-click it, you have a menu option "Clear recent items list".

   [image]

Comment: this only clears this list and not things like the search bar autocomplete on explorer (which even clearing ie doesnt clear)