# How do I clear the Recent Documents list in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, history, cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clear cache/history in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/62776/clear-cache-history-in-windows-7)

How do I remove the list of recent files in Windows 7?

Are those files stored anywhere else?

Comment: Here is a site that will help you and tell you where the docs are stored. It has lots of other hints which show you how to turn this off if required. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2275-recent-programs-turn-off.html

Answer (score 25):

Recent Items listed in the ***start menu*** are stored in:
 `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`

To delete, you can either right-click on *Recent Items* from the start menu and select *Clear recent items list* or you can empty the folder from inside Windows Explorer.

Recent items listed in ***jump lists*** are stored in: 
`%appdata%\microsoft\windows\recent\automaticdestinations`

To delete, empty the folder from inside Windows Explorer, or from the command prompt using
 `del %appdata%\microsoft\windows\recent\automaticdestinations\*`

Comment: Though be aware that deleting those files also has the less desirable effect of also clearing your pinned items in your jump lists. Would be nice to be able to clear the recent items without clearing the pinned ones.

Comment: Just to note browsing to the `%appdata%\microsoft\windows\recent\ ` folder in Explorer will not show you the `automaticdestinations` folder as it is a hidden system folder.  If you want the specific jumplists folder then it is at location `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`

Comment: The files in `%appdata%\microsoft\windows\recent\automaticdestinations
` are binary have coded names so how do I see which file they are a shortcut to?

Comment: @DonaldDuck find your target `automaticdestinations` file by sorting the folder by modified date, then 'Pin' an entry in the target jumplist to modify it - the target file will jump to the top

Answer (score 7):

> How do i remove all recent files in
>   windows-7?

**[Ccleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/)**, a system optimization, privacy and cleaning tool, will clear "all recent files" (and much more).

*Ccleaner is freeware, i recommend [Ccleaner Slim](http://www.ccleaner.com/download/builds) (without browser toolbar).*

Comment: It never hurts to run CCleaner, so if it suits his needs and clean up even more mess, the more the better!