# Windows Recent Items Frequently Erased

Tags: windows-8.1

For the past few weeks, the recent items list for a number of Microsoft programs has been periodically erased:

- Recent Excel files cleared (no recent files shown in the Open dialog).
- Recent Remote Desktop Connection computers cleared (the drop-down is empty, whereas previously it recalled the computers I recently connected to).
- Recent Visual Studio 2013 projects cleared when right-clicking the VS2013 icon, but not from the VS2013 Start Page.

I always log in with the same account and launch the programs as the same user.  History has been completely erased twice that I have noticed.

Is this a known issue?  Any way to fix it?

Comment: You are running some tool that is clearing this content out

Comment: Adding to the above, I guess the most popular of those is CCleaner.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks, found the relevant items under CCleaner / Windows Explorer.  Feel free to add an appropriate answer if you like.

Comment: @EricJ. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Sure but credit should go where credit is due.  I'll add an answer if Ramhound or Molx don't provide one.

Comment: Somebody already asked the [reverse](http://superuser.com/questions/95964/how-do-i-clear-the-recent-documents-list-in-windows-7/95986#95986) of this question though.  I won't be duplicating content.

Comment: Well then close as a duplicate :-)  That sets up a pointer from this question to that one.