# Keep a specific folder from appearing in the Recent list in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Is there a way to keep a specific folder from appearing in the Recent list in Windows Explorer? I would like to keep the desktop from appearing in this list because when I open a file saved on the desktop, it adds Desktop to the Recent list and this is useless because it's possible to click on the Show Desktop button in the taskbar.

Comment: See answer here and see if this method would work? http://superuser.com/questions/95964/how-do-i-clear-the-recent-documents-list-in-windows-7

Comment: @JUICED_IT There was interesting information but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes, this may be one of those deals where it's an all or nothing type of fix. I'm not certain how to easily remove just ONE specific folder from the recent items list easily in an automated fashion but perhaps someone else knows how to do this (registry method?). I know you can purge all and that'd also take care of the folder I assume or you could turn off that Windows functionality off all together -- I'll let someone else answer the question for a specific solution but that's what I have suggestion wise if possible. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2013-recent-items-turn-off.html